# Migrate DataSource configuration to properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource

I am trying to migrate DataSource configuration to Spring Boot properties file (we migrated old Spring application to Spring Boot recently) but I am having problems defining all the required properties. I was trying to follow all the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html) but I am still apparently missing something.

This was the initial DataSource definition in a `@Configuration` file:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(getDataSourceURL());
    try {
        dataSource.setDriverClass(getDriverName());
    }
    catch (final PropertyVetoException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot set driverClass for datasource: ", e);
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

I deleted the bean definition and tried to replace it with the following properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=my_url
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.jooq.sql-dialect=HSQLDB
spring.datasource.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

However, I am getting the following exception during application startup:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@6e599e88 of type class org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:240)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:697)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:526)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5292)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not postProcess org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@6e599e88 of type class org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:347)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Could someone point out to me what am I missing here?

Comment: Instead `spring.datasource.dialect`, try use `spring.jpa.database-platform`.

Comment: @BrunoCésar Unfortunately, this does not work either

Comment: Another way is setup hibernate properties, like this: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect`. Looking at my configurations I not setup dialect, since it's lookup from connection.

Comment: I am getting this exception regardless hwther I specify dialect or not so I assume I must be doing it wrongly. Everything was working with the previous bean definition so I am sure all the other parts of my application are fine and it is something to do with this migration to properties

Comment: I dont't know how exactly is your configutation, so is hard to reproduce here since spring boot has many ways to configure. Particularly I use `datasource.*` and not `spring.datasource.*`, this with boot 1.4.0. In another case, with boot 1.4.2 I use `spring.datasource.*` but with `type` and not `driver-class-name` or `dialect` and `spring.jpa.database-platform` for the dialect. Maybe this help you: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 1.4.1 at the moment

Comment: that exception has nothing to do with the datasource configuration at all. Do you get that when you replace the code above with the properties?

Comment: Yes, it happens after I try to migrate the datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this setting:

```
## JDBC part
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase

spring.datasource.username=useranme
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

You have to add this file in the resources folder with the application.properties name.

Comment: This is almost the same thing I had in my question. I don't need password and username since I dont use those for the local in-memory setup that I am testing right now. Anyway, it still genreates the seame exception

Comment: please add you main class.